# Style custom Class in Extjs 4.2.1

Tags: css, extjs, theming

I created a custom class named Ext.MlButton that extends the Ext.button.Button class.
I used the Ext namespace, as i don't use sencha's mvc system for my app.

Now, i would like to apply some styles ONLY to the MlButton class, without it influencing (or being influenced by) the styles of the Ext.button.Button class.

I tried creating a MlButton.scss file inside the sass/var folder of my custom theme, but the styles applied there do not seem to effect my MlButton.

What can i do?

Comment: did you read the theming guide?

Comment: I did. I thought that since i was defining the custom class inside the ext namespace (I.e. Ext.MlButton) creating a MlButton.scss file inside the sass/var folder would do the trick. But unfortunately, it did not